# How to get the index of compared values from an array of object in angular or javascript

Tags: angular

I have an array of object arraydata, I have some values in an array  myarray. I need to compare those values with arraydata 'name'and get the keys in an array like  myarrayIndex, which is commented now.Here is the code below  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h6m7tg

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular";
  arraydata = [
    { name: "name1", value: 1 },
    { name: "name2", value: 2 },
    { name: "name3", value: 3 },
    { name: "name4", value: 4 }
  ];
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.arraydata);
    const myarray = ["name1", "name2", "name4"];
    //const myarrayIndex = [0,1,3]
  }
}
```

Comment: You want to get the index of those elements which are matched. Correct?

Comment: yes,you are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement it like this:

```js
const arraydata = [
  { name: "name1", value: 1 },
  { name: "name2", value: 2 },
  { name: "name3", value: 3 },
  { name: "name4", value: 4 }
];

const myarray = ["name1", "name2", "name4"];

const matched = arraydata
  .reduce((acc, { name }, index) => myarray.includes(name) ? [...acc, index] : acc , []);

console.log(matched);
```